# Need help connecting elasticsearch server and laravel localhost

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect elasticsearch server to work on my localhost (real-estate-laravel.test). I downloaded and activated elasticsearch and have elastichsearch server running on http://localhost:9200/ , like this

```
{
"name" : "DESKTOP-F9QAVC4",
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"cluster_uuid" : "5br4u4tTTR-xzg7FBeInPg",
 "version" : {
  "number" : "7.3.0",
  "build_flavor" : "default",
  "build_type" : "zip",
  "build_hash" : "de777fa",
  "build_date" : "2019-07-24T18:30:11.767338Z",
  "build_snapshot" : false,
  "lucene_version" : "8.1.0",
  "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
  "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
 },
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And I added in my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.0"
}
```

and entered composer update. I am now confused on how to connect elasticsearch server with my localhost, so when I make some search queries in my controller they will search through elasticsearch. Any help is appreciated. Here is my controller.

CategoryController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Category;
use App\Property;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Category $category, Property $property, User $user)
    {
        $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
        //dd($client);
        if(Auth::check()) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In this if(Auth::check()) will go certain queries. Also when I dump $client I get this

```
Client {#351 ▼
  +transport: Transport {#349 ▶}
  #params: null
  #indices: IndicesNamespace {#352 ▶}
  #cluster: ClusterNamespace {#353 ▶}
  #nodes: NodesNamespace {#354 ▶}
  #snapshot: SnapshotNamespace {#355 ▶}
  #cat: CatNamespace {#356 ▶}
  #ingest: IngestNamespace {#357 ▶}
  #tasks: TasksNamespace {#358 ▶}
  #remote: RemoteNamespace {#359 ▶}
  #endpoints: Closure($class) {#350 ▶}
  #registeredNamespaces: []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch](https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch) package instead.

It allows you to setup your host information at `.env` file easily and use ClientBuilder as your current code.

Comment: Aha, I see. And do I just add these lines ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=localhost
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200 in env or do I replace them with current localhost, password etc. ?

Comment: After that you need to change your builder part like `$client = ClientBuilder::create([env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST') . ':' . env('ELASTICSEARCH_PORT')])->build();`

Comment: @hkulekci I changed it. So now, how can I test this to see if elasticsearch works?

Comment: Create an index. then save (index) some documents. Then search on this index.